# will laravel / codeigniter project files be shown as text, if php engine fails?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, security

new-bee with this question.
so, **enlightened ones**, don't hastily down vote this question.

here's the explanation why this question arose:
in times when PHP engine doesn't start (because of any reason), our PHP code is shown as plain text.
to avoid this, before shifting to laravel, i used to keep code files in parent folder to "public_html" and include it where ever i wanted.
e.g.
my index.php is in:

```
public_html\index.php
```

inside this index file i write

```
include("..\code4index.php");
```

in this case if PHP engine fails, viewer will only see `include("..\code4index.php");` as text 
and as this "code4index.php" is out of the scope of website folder "public_html", it is not accessible.

now i am shifting to laravel.
what will happen if php doesn't start by some reason.
will my code be visible to all?

if yes, what must i do to avoid this?
if CodeIgniter provides this, i would give it a chance.
**i want my code to be inaccessible in any circumstances.**

Answer (score 1):

what will happen if PHP doesn't start by some reason?
will my code be visible to all?

**YES**, it will be visible as normal text. and it will try to execute your index.php or root file of the application.

And you can't achieve this anyway.

Comment: the question is related to laravel / codeigniter.
are u experienced with these frame works?

Comment: Yes, I know it very well.